# ¿Cómo poder iniciar sesión desde el login web de Laravel teniendo configurado JWT?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-8

**EDIT**

Además de lo que describo a continuación, en síntesis, lo que requiero es poder iniciar sesión desde el formulario de login que proporciona nativamente Laravel usando el `username` y `password` de la base de datos y seguir ocupando todas mis apis integradas con JWT.

---

Me encuentro con un problema que quizá sea muy básico y no lo estoy visualizando. En síntesis, tengo un proyecto de laravel 8 funcionando correctamente con apis usando JWT para la parte de tokens.

Resulta que tengo la necesidad de iniciar sesión también desde el login web de laravel (auth login)

A través de mis apis, incluyendo el del `auth/login` todo funciona correctamente, sin embargo al querer iniciar sesión desde el login web no funciona y me redirige a la misma vista del login una vez ingresado el username y el password correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado, entre mis ajustes para hacer funcionar JWT y mis apis, modifiqué mi `LoginController` y mi `AuthController` de forma en que mis apis pudieran iniciar sesión con el campo de `username` de mi base de datos en lugar del clásico campo `email`

Para solucionar mi problema y buscando en internet, probé cambiando algunas rutas en el `api.php`, sin embargo sigue sin funcionar el login en la web y ya no sé qué más pudiera cambiar de forma en que me funcionen mis apis usando JWT y el login web.

Agradeceré cualquier aporte que pudiera ayudarme a solucionar mi problema.

Mis archivos serían estos:

api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use \App\Http\Controllers\RegistrosController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('/refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
    Route::get('/user-profile', [AuthController::class, 'userProfile']);


});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'can:agregar_observaciones', 'can:ver_todos_registros']], function () {
    Route::get("/registros/ver-registros-admin/{registro_id?}", [RegistrosController::class, "verRegistrosAdmin"])->name("registros.ver_registros_admin");
    Route::post("/registros/agregar-observaciones", [RegistrosController::class, "agregarObservaciones"])->name("registros.agregar_observaciones");

});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'can:guardar_nuevos_registros', 'can:ver_registros_usuario']], function () {
    Route::get("/registros/ver-registros-usuario/{registro_id?}", [RegistrosController::class, "verRegistrosUsuario"]);
    Route::post("/registros/guardar-registro", [RegistrosController::class, "guardarRegistro"]);
    Route::post("/registros/agregar-foto", [RegistrosController::class, "saveImage"]);
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Validator;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'username' => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        $response = [
            "data" => [],
            "message" => "Credenciales incorrectas",
            "success" => false,
        ];

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $response;
        }

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($validator->validated())) {
            return $response;
        }

        $auth = $this->createNewToken($token);
        return $response = [
            "data" => $auth,
            "message" => "",
            "success" => true,
        ];;
    }

    /**
     * Register a User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|between:2,100',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:100|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
        }

        $user = User::create(array_merge(
            $validator->validated(),
            ['password' => bcrypt($request->password)]
        ));

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User successfully registered',
            'user' => $user
        ], 201);
    }


    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout() {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'User successfully signed out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh() {
        return $this->createNewToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function userProfile() {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function createNewToken($token){
        $user = auth()->user();
        $user['role'] = $user->roles->pluck('name')->first();
        unset($user['roles']);
        return [
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user' => $user
        ];
        /*return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user' => $user
        ]);*/
    }

}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'username',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Y para finalizar así están compuestas mis rutas:

```
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                                | Name                            | Action                                                                 | Middleware                                 |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                                                  |                                 | Closure                                                                | web                                        |
|        | POST     | api/auth/login                                     |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@login                              | api                                        |
|        | POST     | api/auth/logout                                    |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@logout                             | api                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | auth:api                                   |
|        | POST     | api/auth/refresh                                   |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@refresh                            | api                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | auth:api                                   |
|        | POST     | api/auth/register                                  |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@register                           | api                                        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/auth/user-profile                              |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@userProfile                        | api                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | auth:api                                   |
|        | POST     | api/registros/agregar-foto                         |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\RegistrosController@saveImage                     | api                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | can:guardar_nuevos_registros               |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | can:ver_registros_usuario                  |
|        | POST     | api/registros/agregar-observaciones                | registros.agregar_observaciones | App\Http\Controllers\RegistrosController@agregarObservaciones          | api                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | can:agregar_observaciones                  |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | can:ver_todos_registros                    |
|        | POST     | api/registros/guardar-registro                     |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\RegistrosController@guardarRegistro               | api                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | can:guardar_nuevos_registros               |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | can:ver_registros_usuario                  |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/registros/ver-registros-admin/{registro_id?}   | registros.ver_registros_admin   | App\Http\Controllers\RegistrosController@verRegistrosAdmin             | api                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | can:agregar_observaciones                  |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | can:ver_todos_registros                    |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/registros/ver-registros-usuario/{registro_id?} |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\RegistrosController@verRegistrosUsuario           | api                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\Authenticate |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | can:guardar_nuevos_registros               |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | can:ver_registros_usuario                  |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                                           |                                 | Closure                                                                | api                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | auth:api                                   |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                                               | home                            | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | auth                                       |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                                              | login                           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | guest                                      |
|        | POST     | login                                              |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | guest                                      |
|        | POST     | logout                                             | logout                          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web                                        |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/confirm                                   | password.confirm                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | auth                                       |
|        | POST     | password/confirm                                   |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | auth                                       |
|        | POST     | password/email                                     | password.email                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web                                        |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset                                     | password.request                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web                                        |
|        | POST     | password/reset                                     | password.update                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web                                        |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token}                             | password.reset                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web                                        |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                                           | register                        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | guest                                      |
|        | POST     | register                                           |                                 | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web                                        |
|        |          |                                                    |                                 |                                                                        | guest                                      |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Cuando haces una petición al LoginController, no deberías comprobar el JWT puesto que aún no lo tienes. Ese "endpoint" debería ser de libre acceso.

Comment: Hola, @PabloLozano Haciéndolo desde las apis, por ejemplo, mipagina.com/api/auth/login todo funciona bien, el problema está cuando trato de iniciar sesión en el formulario web del login

Answer (score 1):

Si tu request va por web, el driver de jwt-auth busca si tienes una cookie con nombre 'token'. Si la tienes, y puede validar el payload, trata el resto del request como si hubieses mandado el header de autenticación.

(**Edit**: aunque estoy medianamente convencido de haber visto un setting "cookie" en el config de jwt, no veo que esté en su repositorio ¿Lo habrán deprecado?. Sí comprobé que puedes invocar al método `setKey` desde un service provider [en caso que quieres usar un nombre distinto a "token"](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/blob/ab00f2d7cce5f043067aef7849cdc792de2df635/src/Http/Parser/KeyTrait.php#L12-L22))

Creo que lo más rápido es que apuntes tu ruta `POST /login` al mismo método que el API. `App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::login`.

#### Fijar las cookies en AuthController

En ese método, antes de mandar la respuesta, encolas una cookie:

```
    $auth = $this->createNewToken($token);
    Cookie::queue(
      'token', 
       $auth['access_token'],
       $auth['expires_in']/60 
    );

    return $response = [
        "data" => $auth,
        "message" => "",
        "success" => true,
    ];
```

#### No encriptar esa cookie

Por lo que estuve probando hace unos minutos, si Laravel encripta la cookie el parser de JWTAuth no la logra leer bien (pese a que se supone que lo hace). Para no tener este problema cambiamos en `config/jwt.php` de true a false el desencriptado de la cookie. Sólo afecta a la cookie con nombre `token`

```
  'decrypt_cookies' => false,
```

Y en el middleware `App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies` donde se encriptan las cookies, la eximinos de la encriptación

```
/**
 * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    'token'
];
```

Refrescas el caché de configuración y rutas, y de ahí en adelante puedes navegar por rutas de ambos guards. En auth('web') lee la sesión, y en auth('api') lee la cookie y llena con eso el header de autorización.

#### Fijar las cookies en LoginController

Es posible que quieras manejar el login via web en paralelo, por ejemplo para que la vista de login redirija a una vista y no responda JSON, o para no tener que tocar tus rutas.

En ese caso me funcionó poniendo la cookie en el método `LoginController::authenticated`. y poniendo explícitamente que se usa el guard web

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param mixed                    $user
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $user = $this->guard()->user();
    $token_string = auth('api')
                     ->fromUser($user);
    Cookie::queue('token', $token_string);
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('web');
}
```

#### Custom Claims

No estoy seguro si hoy usas y te funciona que el token tenga el rol del usuario. JWTAuth invoca al método `getJWTCustomClaims` que hoy tienes como un array vacío. Podrías en cambio llenar el rol ahí mismo:

```
/**
 * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getJWTCustomClaims()
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    return ['role'=> $user->roles->pluck('name')->first()];
}
```

Comment: Hola, buenas tardes, gracias por tu explicación, apliqué los cambios pero sigue sin funcionar, en el login web no se puede iniciar sesión, sin embargo a través de las apis todo funciona bien

Comment: Pusiste que al loguearte por web te ponga una cookie 'token' que sea un JWT válido?

Comment: @ffabes así es, lo hice y no funcionó =/

Comment: y que error te sale???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Ya implementé lo que me comentaste y ahora todo funciona bien, ya me hace el login, sin embargo cuando hago el login desde la web me redirige a una página llamada login en donde muestra explícitamente impreso el objeto del user loggeado, ¿sabes cómo hacer para que eso no pase? Gracias y ya casi queda, te agradezco demasiado

Comment: perfecto te felicito, a veces no logramos hacer las cosas por que no sabemos por donde empezar ... creo entonces que ya puedes marcar la pregunta como resuelta

Comment: tambien te recuerdo que te quedan 10 horas para seleccionar una respuesta como la ganadora de los puntos de respuesta.